Kyan Pascal: compiler error "Too many indices on the closing bracket of a[t]"
In Kyan Pascal for the Commodore 64, I keep getting the error:

Too many indices on the closing bracket of a[t]

...in the first line of my first procedure:
  For t := 1 to 100 do a[t] := t;

Whole program:
Program sort;
Type btyp = 1 .. 255;
Var a : array [1..100] of integer;

Procedure generatedata;
Var t     : btyp;
    A,b,r : integer;
Begin
  For t:= 1 to 100 do a[t] := t;
  For t := 1 to 255 do begin
    A := random * 100;
    B := random * 100;
    R := a[a];
  End;
End;

Procedure bubblesort;
Var i,j,k : integer;
Begin
  For i := 1 to 99 do begin
    for j := i to 100 do begin
      If a[i] > a[j] then begin
        K := a[i];
        A[i] := a[j];
        A[j] := k;
      End;
    End;
  End;
End;

Procedure showdata;
Var i : integer;
Begin
  For i := 1 to 100 do begin
    Write(a[i]:3,' ');
  End;
End;

Begin
  Write(chr(147));
  Generatedata;
  Bubblesort;
  Showdata;
End.

Apparently Kyan Pascal doesn't support the byte type. At least every time I use it, I get:

Type identifier expected

...at the beginning of the word "byte".

You need to post a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. You can't post just a line or two totally out of context. The error could be caused by a previous line. The site guidelines require that you provide that [mre] when asking about code that isn't working, as is clearly stated in the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Make sure your title describes the problem in enough detail that people can tell if they're having the same problem (and thus, if your question's answers are likely to help them). Our main goal here is to build a knowledgebase, not to provide 1:1 personal support -- getting assistance when you have a question that isn't already one we have answered is just a happy side effect of working towards that goal. :)

Also, compilers are not too finicky. They do their job, which is to parse the code to make sure that it is syntactically correct. When something does exactly what it's supposed to do, it's not being finicky. If there's an issue, odds are very good that the issue is on your end, not the compilers.

Provide a full routine, not fragments of it where you repeat yourself. Learn to use inline code formatting using backticks. Why do you insist on using a subrange typed variable as ordinal for your loop - why not an Integer right away?

I did originally use integer, but got the same error message.  Thinking it was thinking the index could go out of bounds, i switched to byte.  That worked in another program on kyan, but not here.  So i tried limiting the range, and still no help.  Which is why I asked on here, but apparently no one knows on here either.

... but apparently no one knows on here either. Knows what, exactly? Did you already correct your error with the clashing variable names "a" as in a: array[1..100] of integer and "A" as in A: integer. As you have been told a and A are the same identifiers, but you are using them as they would be distinct.

The manual for Kyan Pascal 1.0 tells us in "TUTORIAL IV: INTEGERS AND FOR LOOPS" (page 34, PDF wise page 110):

Integers are most commonly used in FOR loops, although it is possible to use Real number variables.

What you try to use for a loop is a subrange ("TUTORIAL IV: SCALAR VARIABLES", pages 60-61, PDF wise pages 136-137):

The Subrange TYPE is a form of the Scalar TYPE because it is a list of items. It is different, however, because you need to specify only the first and last items in the range. Obviously, if the subrange is a list of names, the full list must be defined in a Scalar TYPE. Subranges may contain integers since the computer understands the list of numbers as a Subrange of the entire set of Integers it uses. The syntax of the TYPE Subrange is:
TYPE
  Name = first item .. last item;

The following sample declaration illustrates the use of Scalar and Subrange TYPES. ... Finally, a Subrange of integers is defined. After the TYPE declarations have been made, Variables are identified as their respective TYPES.
TYPE
  Days = 1..7;
VAR
  DayNum : Days;


There's no guarantee that subrange typed variable can be used as an ordinal for a for loop - most likely because Kyan Pascal implements ISO Standard Pascal (and that doesn't know any Byte type). In any Delphi compiler or with FPC a for loop would accept a subrange typed variable, as in:
type
  btyp= 1.. 255;
var
  t: btyp;
begin
  for t:= 1 to 100 do Caption:= IntIoStr( t );

However, I don't find your stated compiler error message in Appendix C, pages 1-4 (PDF wise pages 285-288) - you must be using a later version.

ISO Pascal is case insensitive: declaring both a and A is not possible.

Var a : array [1..100] of integer;

Procedure generatedata;
Var A : integer;
Begin
  For t:= 1 to 100 do a[t] := t;


At this point you want to access a, but effectively access A - and that variable doesn't support indices at all - hence the compiler error. In general variables should have meaningful names, so a better name for a might be unsorted, and a better name for A might be rand1 - that would have avoided this kind of mistake right away. Not the "darn compiler is too finicky" - you were a bit lazy about naming the variables.
Your entire program suffers from more logical mistakes: R := a[a]; doesn't make sense, and in Procedure bubblesort you even do A[i] := a[j];, being insensitive to casing yourself.

I changed it back to integer, and get the same exact error message as before.  0010    for t := 1 to 100 do a[t] := t;  then a 1 under the closing ], followed by (1)  too many indices ...  sorry, but replies don't get formatting options.

Version 2.1 for the commodore 64.  Copyright 1984 by kyan software.

Finally, someone with usefull help!  That fixed it!  Now if i could just find a random routine!

So I have linked to the documentation in vain - you could have used CTRL+F on the PDF to find page 73: "RANDOM NUMBERS".
